# php envío de valor por url que no funciona

Tags: php, url

uso una url para pasar una pk a otra página, pero no me llega, isset la revisa y la muesta como no definida

```
while($fila=mysqli_fetch_array($resultados, MYSQLI_ASSOC))  
        {               
            echo "<tr align='center'>";
            echo "<td>". $fila['identificacion'] . "</td>";

            echo "<td>". $fila['nombre'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>". $fila['direccion'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>". $fila['telefono'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>". $fila['correo'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>". $fila['sexo'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>". $fila['estado_civil'] . "</td>";   
            echo '<td><a href="cuenta_ingresar.php?identificacion='.$fila['identificacion'].'">Seleccionar</a></td>';               
            echo "</tr>";           

        }
```

y llega a

```
<?php

 if(isset($_POST['identificacion'])){
        $identificacion = $_POST['identificacion'];
```

Comment: La estas pasando por GET. prueba $_GET['identificacion'];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cuando el valor va por url se usa `$_GET` (pedir) pues se considera parte de la url/petición

cuando el valor va por formulario se usa `$_POST` (poner/meter/publicar)

hay un array agnóstico que es `$_REQUEST` (contiene los valores de $_GET, $_POST y $_COOKIE)

volviendo a tu ejemplo puedes usar :

```
if(isset($_GET['identificacion'])){
    $identificacion = $_GET['identificacion'];
```

ó

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['identificacion'])){
    $identificacion = $_REQUEST['identificacion'];
```

Answer (score 0):

los valores que estas usando son de get no de post para eso tienes que usar el $_GET["parametro"] pero si la pagina a la cual quieres mandar ese valor por el url es de tu mismo sitio hay formas mucho mejores y estéticas para hacerlo por ejemplo usar varibles de sesion. 
nota: los post normalmente se hacen con un form y un submit o tambien mediante ajax

Comment: Cierto, gracias Alo, gracias Pablo, gracias Rubencho